# PostgreSQL - where datetime <= YEAR-MONTH-DAY, ignore time

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, datetime, timestamp

date column - datetime type.

My query is:

```
select * from car_db.car_parts where date::text LIKE '2018-07-06%'
```

How i `select where date <= 'YEAR-MONTH-DAY'`, and ignore time?

I will be grateful...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following. Also, you should not name your column as date.

```
select * from car_db.car_parts where cast("date" as date) < '2018-07-06'
```

Comment: and, i replaced from "<" to "<="

Answer (score 6):

First, Postgres doesn't offer a `datetime` type.  The type is called `timestamp`.  Also, Postgres has the very convenient function `date_trunc()`, so you can use that:

```
select *
from car_db.car_parts
where date_trunc('day', date) = '2018-07-06'::date;
```

However, this method -- or any method with a functional call or type conversion -- can affect index usage.  I strongly recommend:

```
where date >= '2018-07-06'::date and
      date < '2018-07-07'::date
```